# Customize Azure AD token using Client Credential Grant Type

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an API `api/GetPets` which is being used by multiple clients which are API's as well `ClientA, ClientB` having same Azure client Id `*****`.

While `ClientA` authenticates  and uses `api/GetPets` , I want to get client name in the token or some way to identify the client calling the API .Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way you differentiate calling client apps is by them using different client ids.

If you want to tell the difference between them, you must register them separately so that they have different client ids.

Comment: considering moving to separate client id as not being a feasible option for now, would there be any other workaround for the problem. Customizing tokens, on-behalf of requests or something. @juunas

Comment: Token customization is done at app registration level, so would affect both clients since they are using the same one. On-behalf-of includes the user info, but the application claims would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

@junnas's answer is correct and probably the best approach. The only other way I can think of is passing the client name explicitly on the HTTP request, However; this only works for clients that are 100% trusted. Otherwise there's nothing stopping any client with a valid auth token tampering with the client name on the HTTP request. If the client name is in the signed auth token (JWT), any tampering would be detected and blocked.